# Missing cSYM message on Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics

I got this error message today on Crashytics

*We're missing your symbol file to fully process NDK crashes. Learn how to upload it here!*

and I havent found a way to upload the said file. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hey Alex, Mike from Crashlytics here. This is a UI bug on our end and we're working on a fix for this currently. Sorry for the confusion, but your app is good to go!

Comment: Seems to be related to Crashlytics for Android NDK: http://crashlytics.com/blog/the-wait-is-over-launching-crashlytics-for-android-ndk

Comment: It's all good now. Thanks a lot @MikeB